# How to create Generic class that takes unlimited type

Tags: c#, generics

I want to create a Generic class that can take unlimited types. I mean;

If i want to create a generic class that takes 2 different types i have to write it like below;

```
public class ClassName<T1, T2> { }
```

But if i want to create a generic class that takes 3 different types i have to write it like below;

```
public class ClassName<T1, T2, T3> { }
```

But i want to create a class that can take 2 or 3 or more different types without creating new classes. With just one class definition.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# does not support variadic generics, so no, what you're describing is not possible.  What specific problem are you trying to solve?